# How do we load a WebVtt file in React?

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, loader, webvtt

This is my data structure

WEBVTT

00:00:15.000 --> 00:00:17.951
At the left we can see...

00:00:18.166 --> 00:00:20.083
At the right we can see the...

00:00:20.119 --> 00:00:21.962
...the head-snarlers

I am trying to parse a web vtt file. For this I wrote :

```
     var data = require('./captions.en.vtt');
```

Error

client:47 ./src/captions.en.vtt
Module parse failed: C:\Users\sampr\Desktop\MyVIew\WebVtt\src\captions.en.vtt Invalid number (3:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.

Could someone please help me?

Answer (score 2):

You need a appropriate loader for the file type (.vtt).

Install [file-loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/file-loader) (`npm install --save-dev file-loader`) and you could use it directly like this:

```
var data = require('file-loader!./captions.en.vtt');
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Next.js, I ended up using [this solution](https://vercel.com/guides/loading-static-file-nextjs-api-route).

> ...add a file called staticdata.js inside the pages/api folder. This will create a Serverless Function that will load the json data from the file, and return it as a response.

Basically the solution is to return the data from an API endpoint.